# asking 2 questions for one response mail merge

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

So far my If statement looks like

```
{IF {MERGEFIELD style } = "luxury" {IF MERGEFIELD type} = "house" "this is a expensive choice" {IF {MERGEFIELD type} = "flat" "This is a cheap flat" "this is cheap house"} } "this is a cheap house"}
```

if the customer wants a flat(luxury and standard) it should be saying "this is a cheap flat"

if the customer wants a standard house it should be saying " this is a cheap house"

if the customer wants a luxury house it should be sayings " this is a expensive choice"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this set of nested fields instead:
[image]

Comment: Out of interest- why use an image that OP will have to type out manually, rather than text in a code box which can be copied and pasted?

Comment: As it was all fields, I had assumed they would insert them and not type (also eliminates risk of them typing { } instead of actually inserting fields).

Comment: Gotcha, cheers! (it wasn't me who DV'd, incidentally)